# How to change the version of facebook API that the 'Facebook SDK for Python" uses

Tags: python-2.7, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using the 'Facebook SDK for Python" ( https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk   )

I want to be able to set the version of the Facebook API that this package uses. I have searched, but can't seem to see anywhere on how to make the change. The following code is included in part of the chnagelog... and I suspect that someone who is not relatively new to python/facebook may be able to spot from this how it should be defined.

```
 def __init__(self, access_token=None, timeout=None, version=None):
     # The default version is only used if the version kwarg does not exist.
     default_version = "1.0"
  -  valid_API_versions = ["1.0", "2.0", "2.1"]
  +   valid_API_versions = ["1.0", "2.0", "2.1", "2.2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should set `default_version` to whatever version you want to use, update the `valid_API-versions` list to include that version, and make sure none of the calls to `__init__` are overriding the version with the `version` parameter

Comment: I have tried passing the version number when ccallign the function e.g. 

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token, version="2.2") however get the error:

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'version'   ... not sure why...

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the code you can see that the version can be passed either as a string or as a float since the module will do a `str(version)` anyway.

Both of the following will work:

```
facebook.GraphAPI(access_token, version=2.2)

facebook.GraphAPI(access_token, version="2.2")
```